# Reorganizing Indexes took long time

Tags: sql, indexing

I am using SQL Server 2005 with a daily maintenance plan.Today I noticed that REORGANIZING INDEXES task took around 10 hours which is weird comparing to the previous one (max 20 min). My database size is 20 Gb. Is this normal or there is something wrong?

Comment: Daily Task for REORGANIZING INDEXES without checking fragmentation to see whether any maintenance is needed or not ???

Comment: My maintenance plan tasks are as follow :
1- Check Database Integrity
2- Shrink Database
3- Reorganizing Index
4- Back Up Database